# Which path type allows repeated vertices and edges when traversing data in NebulaGraph?

Tags: nebula-graph

Which path type allows repeated vertices and edges when traversing data in NebulaGraph?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/1.introduction/2.1.path/#walk

The answer is the walk.

> A walk is a finite or infinite sequence of edges. Both vertices and edges can be repeatedly visited in graph traversal.